# Why does SQL Server 2019 Developer installation fail?

Tags: sql-server

When running the installer for SQL Server 2019 Developer, it always fails to install SQL Client Connectivity SDK, which is a pre-requisite for just about every other feature.  The messages are very cryptic and are not providing any useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered this article stating that the issue has to do with a combination of having Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client installed and running the 2019 installation from a DVD.  You have the option to either remove 2012 Native Client or to copy the DVD contents to a drive to get the installation to succeed.  I copied the files locally and was able to perform the 2019 installation.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server-Support/SQL-Server-2019-Installation-Error-An-error-occurred-for-a/ba-p/998033

Comment: it was failing for me in the normal database engine part. Uninstalling the native client did the trick for me. This article helped me.
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-curious-case-of-the-failing-sql-server-2019-install/

Comment: i needed 2 engine instances, so i kept my own and copied the disc files to hard drive and ran it from there. it worked fine. i guess it has something to do with it not being able to write data to the disc etc...